# How to integrate $\frac{1}{\sin(x)+2}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to find the indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{\sin(x)+2}$. I know that the integral of $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ can be easily obtained by $x:=2u$, and the final solution is $\ln(\tan(x/2))$. However, I do not know how to handle the shift in the denominator. Thank you, in advance, for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [tan half substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) solves this

$$\int\frac{1}{\sin x + 2}\mathrm{d}x \underset{u=\tan\frac{x}{2}}= \int\frac{2}{(u^2+1)(\frac{2u}{u^2+1}+2)}\mathrm{d}u = \int\frac{1}{1+u+u^2}\mathrm{d}u$$

Finishing from here should not be that hard.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is correct and the final results is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan \frac{2\tan(x/2)+1}{\sqrt{3}}$.